# Log requests to a flask server using gunicorn as wsgi server ... to AWS cloudwatch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gunicorn

I am using a flask server with gunicorn as the wsgi server.

I want to log all requests details to cloudwatch.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return jsonify({
            'logging': "I want to log this request to cloudwatch", 
            "request": request
        })

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

one way to to setup a logger, and use watchtower

https://watchtower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-flask-logging-with-watchtower

```
import watchtower, flask, logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
app = flask.Flask("loggable")
handler = watchtower.CloudWatchLogHandler()
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
logging.getLogger("werkzeug").addHandler(handler)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    logging.info("I want to log this request to cloudwatch")
    return jsonify({
        "request": request
    })

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: `logging.info("I want to log this request to cloudwatch")` this line doesn't appear in cloudwatch when i try